# Визуализация окна папки

Tags: visual-studio, c#

Здравствуйте!

Каким образом отобразить, т.е. вывести на экран окно папки?

К примеру была создана папка, а в ней файл, с некоторым содержимым, и в конце всего этого нужно открыть окно папки.

Как это реализовать средствами языка C#?

Спасибо.

Comment: вы имеете ввиду, как запустить окно обозревателя с этой папкой? или что-то другое?

Comment: Да, проводник)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
void Main()
{
    ...
    string PathToMyFolder = "C:\\MyFolder";
    Process.Start(PathToMyFolder);
    ...
}
```

узнать больше про [Process.Start](http://www.dotnetperls.com/process-start)

Comment: Ок, спасибо)